# How to setup a SAML SP with an Idp via REst or Soap Web API

Tags: onelogin, scim

We have a vendor membership management solution to manage our members, Netforum Pro.  They provide a Web API via Rest or Soap for external applications to authenticate.

We would like to use Moodle as Learning Management System for our members.  However, Moodle has an authentication plugin for SAML.

Can we use OneLogin as a middle agent in this situation?

Thanks
Linh N.

Comment: please add more details

Answer (score 0):

OneLogin acts as Identity Provider and has toolkits that will help you authenticate requests when used by application providers. In your case it looks like Moodle has already the functionality that you would implement with the OL toolkit and that NetForum is the Identity Provider. So using OneLogin won't help much.

You should look into http://documentation.abila.com/netforum-enterprise/2017.1/Content/Admin/Security/SAML.htm